# App is not listed in Chrome Web Store after publishing

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Apps Marketplace app that I have recently published to the world.

I have completed the Marketplace Listing Review request, the app appears correctly in the Google Admin console widget, but it is not listed in the actual CWS under "https://chrome.google.com/webstore".

If I visit the CWS app's URL I can see the app and I am able to install it on my domain, but why can't I search for it/find it listed in the CWS? Are app listings on the Google Apps Marketplace and CWS mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the two are mutually exclusive but I am sure they will try to change this in future.

This has also happened to our app. We upgraded an existing chrome Webstore app to use the new OAuth 2 and then submitted it to the App Marketplace. When it was approved to the App Marketplace it disappeared from the Chrome Webstore.

We ended up creating a separate Webstore app to get around it (which is far from ideal).